# get user's current page

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com

How do i get the current SF URL that a user is on when they click a link?

The issue is that I need to put a link in the left nav, do some stuff, and then send them back to the page. The way I'm going about this is creating a visualforce page which is blank and then does the re-direct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should be available as the HTTP Referrer. You can access it in your controller with:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Referer');
```